# How to remove Table rows and append other rows via ajax call?

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, jquery

Hello every one I want to send ajax call and on success I want to remove all  elements in my table and append new  elements according to data returned on success

I have this method to ajax call data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/tweety-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/twitter/tiles/feeds',
          data: {username: $("#username").val()},
          success: function(data){
            function(){
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    $.childern("#followerFeeds").remove()
                    $("#followerFeeds").append("<tr><td>"+data[1].message+ "</td></tr>"
                             +"<tr><td>"+data[1].messageDate+"</td></tr>");
                    }

                }
          }
        });
        }, 3000);
```

and in the page this is the table I need to repopulate:

```
<table id="followerFeeds" style='width: 100%'>
        <tr></tr>
        <c:forEach var="msg" items="${userFeeds}">
        <tr><td>${msg.message}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>${msg.messageDate}</td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: $.childern  should be $.children.  not sure if this was just a typo in the question, or in your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/tweety-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/twitter/tiles/feeds',
          data: {username: $("#username").val()},
          success: function(data){
            function(){
                var table = $("#followerFeeds");
                table.find("tr").remove();

                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    table.append("<tr><td>"+data[1].message+ "</td></tr>"
                             +"<tr><td>"+data[1].messageDate+"</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
          }
        });
        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `success` callback to this:

```
success: function(data){
            function(){
                $("#followerFeeds").html('');
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    $("#followerFeeds").append("<tr><td>"+data[1].message+ "</td></tr>"
                             +"<tr><td>"+data[1].messageDate+"</td></tr>");
                    }

                }
          }
```

1) You spelt `children` wrong.
2) I think clearing the `html` looks simpler

Comment: It was spelt wrong. Also, nothings wrong with it, but you are using it to loop through and clear each item, when you could do that in less time with html('');